# Display on page xml file from storage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

im trying to grab a xml file from my storage and than show it on a url, but is not working, the page is blank, the issue is not in the route, it must me in my code, can someone tell me where is the problem?

Code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(storage_path('app\file.xml'));
return \Response::make($xml , '200')->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

Comment: Sure, it seems like you're not outputting anything

Comment: If the page is blank, it is almost certainly because you have a fatal error, and need to either turn on `display_errors` or find your log file.

Comment: But the xml have content. Dont understand what do you mean.

Comment: The display errors is active

Answer (score 0):

`\Response::make` expects you to pass a string with the content you want to return, but you are passing an object: `simplexml_load_file` returns a `SimpleXMLElement` instance.

As it happens, a `SimpleXMLElement` can be converted to a string, but it won't return the full XML, just the content of that element - it's so that you can do things like `$xml = simplexml_load_string('<doc><message>Hello, World!</message></doc>); $message = (string)$xml->message;`

If you just want the full contents of the XML file, without any changes, you don't need to parse it with SimpleXML at all, just load the contents into a string:

```
$xml_string = file_get_contents(storage_path('app\file.xml'));
return \Response::make($xml_string , '200')->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

If the idea is that you'll be manipulating it later, so you want the object, then you need to call `->asXML()` to turn it back into a string:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(storage_path('app\file.xml'));
#TODO: Do something interesting with $xml
$xml_string = $xml->asXML();
return \Response::make($xml_string , '200')->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```